# Inline validation for Number type input in lightning-datatable

Tags: validation, lightning-datatable, number, type, inline-editing

Is there any way to validate input field of type number in lightning-datatable, like it is in input field of type currency?
I want to have 3 maximum fraction digits. And check validation on inline edit the same way as it is in case of currency type, with red label warning.

LWC

```
    const columns = [
         {
label: 'Currency Fields', 
fieldName: 'curr', 
type: 'currency', 
typeAttributes: { step: "0.001", maximumFractionDigits: 3} },
         {
label: 'Number Fields', 
fieldName: 'num', 
type: 'number', 
typeAttributes: { /*there is no step property...*/ } }
    ];
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to SFSE. Please read [How to Ask](/help/how-to-ask) then [edit] your question to include detail of what you have tried and where you are stuck. Without this information it is likely your question will be closed without answer.